# how to run script with simple command

Tags: terminal

I have project structure like this

```
project
  |app
  |script
```

inside script folder, there are files such as 'run'

run file content:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm start
```

I want to run the file 'run' while I'm at the root of my project by typing only command 'run'. How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is sh file. In order to execute sh file on linux this file has to be executable.

Make sure this file has X permission.

If there is no x permission on file simply execute the command

```
chmod +x run.sh
```

Then execute the file by typing

```
./run.sh
```

For windows you need to create **.bat** file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `run` file in the `script` directory is executable (if not, run `chmod +x script/run`), it can be executed by running `./script/run`.

If you want to avoid having to type the name of the directory (`script`), you could append the `script` directory to your `PATH` environment variable. If you’re running a POSIX compatible shell (not `csh` or `tcsh`), this can be done using:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/project/script"
```

This will allow you to run *any* executable command in the `script` directory without having to specify the name of the directory, e.g., `run`.

NB: be sure that there aren’t common command names in the `script` directory as these commands can be run from any directory (including outside the project directory) after it has been added to the `PATH`. That’s also why I suggest adding it to the **end** of the `PATH` (so it’s the *last* directory that’s searched for executable commands).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want but assuming you need a way to execute a file from node.js, you can use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module and `child_process.exec` method to start any executable.